# I’m trying to find out the name of a book or graphic novel about a person who can freeze time

Tags: story-identification, graphic-novel

I remember reading about a story quite a few years ago but I don’t recall the name, format, or to be honest if I’ve actually just dreamt it. It periodically pops into my head and I really want a copy if it exists.

I believe the plot is that there is a man with the ability to freeze time. He doesn’t use this power much but one day finds out that the whole of London is about to be destroyed. He freezes time and starts moving people out of the area. He doesn’t have any other abilities so this ends up taking him decades and he continues to age. He dies saving everyone but they don’t know who he is.

I have the feeling it’s a graphic novel but I’m not sure why.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when you read this?  (i.e. approximately what year?)  How will London be destroyed?

Answer (score 3):

Could this be the graphic novel *[Whatever Happened to the World's Fastest Man?](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/7877679)* by Dave West?

> Bobby Doyle can stop time.A very large bomb is going to destroy a very large area of London.What should Bobby do?
>
> [image]

[image]